# iPhone 5s trouble with cellular data

Tags: ios, iphone, cellular-data

My iPhone won't send texts and I can't recive any texts unless I'm on Wi-Fi.  My iPhone says I have LTE but nothing that requires internet will load. I have cellular data for all my apps turned on. I've tried rebooting my iPhone, and turning the cellular data off and on. My family members who are hooked up with the same data package can use their data just fine. Any advice on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Call your cellular service provider, they should be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be going over the data limit on my plan.

Comment: I thought that you said that you and your family share a data plan.

Comment: @RedEagle2000 thought we did, sorry!

Answer (score -1):

Check this troubleshooting article ;

https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT201415